# How to pass variables to awk command with conditions?

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have a while loop which reads data from a file with city names:

**city_name:**

```
COIMBATORE
MADURAI
PONDICHERRY
SALEM
TRIPUR
TIRUCHI
TIRUNELVELI
TUTUCORIN
VELLORE
```

and using an `awk` command within the `while` loop and trying to read the variable defined in while loop body again in the `awk` statement however, this is not working and giving me errors. I understand that the `awk` requires the variables to be defined for its body separately to enable `awk` to understand the variable usage and could read its value.

My while loop is like the following:

```
while read city
do
        awk -F, '{
                        if ( $1 == "ACTIVE" ) &&
                        ( $2 == "$city" )
                        print $1
                }' siteDBName >> count

        SUM=`awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' count`

done < city_name
```

where the siteDBName file contains the multiple columns with data like the following:

**siteDBName:**

```
ACTIVE,COIMBATORE,MGT500,1,5,7....
INACTIVE,MADURAI,GT500,5,6,7...
ACTIVE,SALEM,TR600,6,4,6...
ACTIVE,COIMBATORE,GT500,4,5,6...
..
..
```

Here, i tried using the `awk -v c=$city` along with rest of the statements but this too gave me errors.

How can i use the variable used and initialized in the while loop inside the awk statement inside this while loop?

Comment: Don't use `$city`, with `awk -v c=$city`, you must use variable `c` inside `awk` instead. Your best choice should be passing through environment variable `c=$city awk ...` then inside `awk`, use `ENVIRON["c"]`

Comment: What kind of error do you get when using `awk -v c=$city`? as cuonglm states you must use `c` inside awk to referer to the while loop's city. Have in mind that `c` inside awk must be referenced without the $ (it's not bash, it's awk) just c (for instance {print c})

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two basic choices: i) use `-v` to pass the variable to `awk` or ii) close the `'` around the `awk` script, use the shell variable and continue the `'` again.

1. Use `-v`

   ```
   while read city
   do
       awk -v city="$city" -F, '{
                                 if ( $1 == "ACTIVE"  && $2 == city ){print $1}
                                }' siteDBName >> count
   done < city_name
   ```
2. Close the quote

   ```
   while read city
   do
       awk  -F, '{
                    if ( $1 == "ACTIVE"  && $2 == "'$city'" ){print $1}
                 }' siteDBName >> count
   done < city_name
   ```

I removed the `SUM=` line since it wasn't doing anything useful given that `$1` is `ACTIVE` so adding it makes no sense. See my alternate approach below for a way to do this correctly.

Also, note that with this approach, you need to read the `siteDBName` file multiple times. A more efficient version would be:

```
$ awk -F, '{
             if(NR==FNR){cities[$1]++;}
             else if($1=="ACTIVE" && $2 in cities ){sum++}
            } END{print sum,"active cities"}' city_name siteDBName 
3 active cities
```

Comment: Hi @terdon, thank you for the answer! However, could you explain how `"'$city'"` works here?

Comment: @Ch'enMeng in the while loop? When you want to iterate over a file, you do `while read variable; do command $variable; done < file` or, to iterate over a list of files, say, you can do `for variable in *; do command $variable; done`. See, for example https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/While_loop. Or just search for "shell loop tutorial".

Comment: sorry for my unclear question. Indeed, I know the use of while loop. Actually, I wonder to know how the shell variable `$variable` works in `awk`. You know, using `$variable` directly in `awk` is not going to work, but why `$variable` with a pair of single quotes and a pair of double quotes does work?

Comment: @Ch'enMeng I am passing the variable to awk using its `-v` option

Comment: @glennjackman uhm. Good question. In my defense, it was a while ago. I removed that line, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer !

Answer (score 2):

Just as @cuonglm and @YoMismo stated, you are using the wrong variable and the wrong way to reference it. It should be something like:

```
while read city
do
        awk -v c="$city" -F, '{
                        if ( $1 == "ACTIVE"  && $2 == c )
                        print $1
                }' siteDBName >> count
        SUM=`awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' count`

done < city_name
```

Comment: You can use the "edited" link, that takes you to the edit history. And you can leave a comment to anyone who edited your question by adding a `@` before their name: `@terdon`.

Answer (score 1):

If you interested just in SUM

```
grep -cf <(sed s/^/\^ACTIVE,/ city_name) siteDBName
```

or for big files

```
grep -f city_name siteDBName | grep -c ^ACTIVE
```

Answer (score -2):

Try below

```
awk '/1CORP/ && /'$Param1'/ && /REGN/ && /'$Param2'/{print NR":"$0}' $lInputFile
```

The above command will take $Param1 as first parameter and $Param2 as second parameter and will do a search for below criteria

'LCORP%%REGN% in the file passed in the variable `$lInputFile` and will print the line which matches entire string with the line number.

Comment: I don't think this does what you think it does.