# Pass script argument on an awk command

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, arguments

I have a pipe-delimited file and I need to grep the first column and if a pattern matched, I will print the whole line. The command below is working but when I put it on a script, I think the `$1` is conflicting the command:

Command:

```
awk -F'|' < filename '{if ($1 == "stringtomatch") print $0}'
```

Script:

```
./scripts.sh stringtomatch
```

Command in script:

```
awk -F'|' < filename '{if ($1 == "$1") print $0}'
```

The `$1` enclosed in the double quotes is the argument passed to the script. Any advise how to make this work?

Comment: Welcome! I would rename the argument, for example: `arg="$1"; awk -v var="$arg" '{ print var }'`

Comment: Related: [Environment variable not expanded inside the command line argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162672/environment-variable-not-expanded-inside-the-command-line-argument)

Comment: It worked! Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass variables to awk command with conditions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218753/how-to-pass-variables-to-awk-command-with-conditions) (although note that [this answer on SO is more exhaustive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/12231187)).

Answer (score 5):

Note that you can greatly simplify your `awk`. The default action if an expression evaluates to `true` is to print the current line. So this does the same thing:

```
awk -F'|' < filename '$1 == "string"'
```

Anyway, you can use the `-v` option to pass a variable. So your script can be:

```
#/bin/sh

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "At least one argument is required"
  exit
fi

## Allow the script to get the filename from the 2nd argument, 
## default to 'filename' if no second argument is given
file=${2:-filename}

awk -F'|' -v str="$1" '$1 == str' "$file"
```

Comment: awk will also take the filename `-` to mean stdin. So making that declaration into `file="${2:--}"` will use stdin if no filename is supplied. There is a variant that will pass either a list of files or `-` from the command line, but you would need to shift $1 off first.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant ooh, nice, thanks. I won't add it to the answer though since the OP was already hardcoding the file name, so I am assuming they prefer to have a file. Great trick for next time though!